# SwiftUI View doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, combine

My View doesn't update when I change a property in an Array in the `ObservableObject` Class. I even declared a `objectWillChange` property and called it manually but the View just updated randomly or not how i want to. I don't understand this.

```swift
import Foundation
import SocketIO
import Combine

class SocketService: ObservableObject {
    static let instance = SocketService()

    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(RequestURL.base_url)!)
    let socket: SocketIOClient
//    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    @Published var allMessages: [Message] = []
//        {
//        willSet {
//            self.objectWillChange.send()
//        }
//    }
    @Published var writtenUsers: [PreviewMessage] = []
//        {
//        willSet {
//            self.objectWillChange.send()
//        }
//    }

    init() {
        socket = manager.defaultSocket
        setSocketEvents()
    }

    // This method is called
    func recieve_read_all_messages() {
        socket.on("recieve-read-all-messages") { (data, ack) in
            guard let arr = data as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
            guard let userID = arr[0]["userID"] as? Int else {
                print("no userID, \(#function), line: \(#line)"); return
            }

            // self.objectWillChange.send()
            for msg in self.allMessages {
                // Here im trying to change the property in the array
                msg.content.readStatus = .read
            }
    }    
}
```

Even when i directly change this property the view doesn't update

```swift
@EnvironmentObject private var socketService: SocketService

var body: some View {
    VStack {
         List(filteredMessages, id: \.content.uuid, rowContent: chatSpeechBubbleView)
         sendView
    }
}

private func chatSpeechBubbleView(forMessage message: Message) -> some View {
        ChatSpeechBubble(message: message)
    }

private var sendView: some View {
        Button(action: sendMessage) {
            SFSymbol(.paperplane_fill)
                .fontSize(20)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .rotate(.degrees(45))
                .padding(10)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
                .backgroundColor(.blue)
                .clipCircle()
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 2)
    }

    func sendMessage() {
        for msg in socketService.allMessages {            
            msg.content.readStatus = .read
        }
    }
```

My other view where it should be updated:

```swift
struct DoubleCheckmark: View {
    var messageContent: MessageContent

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            SFSymbol(.checkmark)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            SFSymbol(.checkmark)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .padding(.leading, -9)
        }
        .height(13)
        .foregroundColor(self.messageContent.readStatus == .read ? .blue : .gray)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ChatSpeechBubble: View {

    // MARK: - init variables
    var message: Message

    // MARK: - normal variables
    var ownSendMessage: Bool {
        message.fromUser.id == UDService.shared.user.id
    }

    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        messageContent
    }

    private var messageContent: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            if message.content.text != nil {
                Text(message.content.text!)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            if message.content.imageURL != nil {
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            Text(message.content.timeHourMinute)
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

            if ownSendMessage {
                DoubleCheckmark(messageContent: self.message.content)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use `struct`, not `class`

The problem is that `Message` and its subtypes should be declared as a `struct`, rather than a `class`. Here's why.

Here is a basic example I made to demonstrate the difference:

#### Main part of code

```
class SomeObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User(username: "George", password: "password")]
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var object = SomeObject()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")

        let _ = print("Body")
    }
}


let content = ContentView()
print(content.object)
content.object.users[0].password = "password123"
```

#### `User` as a `struct`

```
struct User {
    var username: String
    var password: String
}
```

#### `User` as a `class`

```
class User {
    var username: String
    var password: String

    init(username: String, password: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }
}
```

| `struct` | `class` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: struct] | [image: class] |

Have a look at the print logs at the bottom. With a `struct`, "Body" gets printed again, but why?

This is because classes are passed by reference, and structs are passed by value. This means that you can mutate the properties of the instance of a class, like so:

```
import SpriteKit

let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
sprite.color = .red
```

If `SKSpriteNode` would have been a `struct`, with `let` properties, you would get an error for trying to change a `let` constant:

> `Cannot assign to property: '*' is a 'let' constant`

### Conclusion

So because `Message` is a `class` the **instance** isn't changing. But with a `struct`, the whole thing **is** changing. You need to change the whole thing (by using a `struct`) so `@Published` & `StateObject`/`ObservableObject` can observe the change.