# SwiftUI not updating NavigationLink destination

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have simplified all my code down to this, you can run it to test:

**ContentView.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($viewModel.databases, id: \.name) { $database in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: {
                        VStack {
                            if database.isOpen {
                                Text("Opened!")
                            } else {
                                Text("Closed!")
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        DatabaseItem( database: $database )
                    }
                )
            }
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

class Database {
    var name: String
    var password: String?
    var isOpen: Bool { password != nil }
    
    init(_ name: String, password: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var databases: [Database] = [
        Database("main"), Database("test", password: "123")
    ]
    
    func close(_ db: Database) {
        db.password = nil
    }
}

struct DatabaseItem: View {
    @Binding var database: Database
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: database.isOpen ? "lock.open.fill" : "lock.fill")
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            Text(database.name)
            Spacer()
        }
        .swipeActions {
            if database.isOpen {
                Button(
                    action: { viewModel.close(database) },
                    label: { Image(systemName: "lock.fill") }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TestApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The UI looks like this:
[image]

**Explanation**

The `ViewModel` holds a list of databases. Each database can be in 2 states: opened or closed. If `password` of a database is `nil` – the database is closed, otherwise it's opened (as is represented by the `isOpen` computed property).

We draw a list of database items: a name of each database, and a lock icon representing whether the database is opened or closed.

When you select a database item from the list, you go to the next screen. If you select opened database, you go to the screen that says "Opened!". If you selected closed database, you go to screen saying "Closed!".

Now, opened databases have an action (you can swipe left on a database item to reveal it) to close the database. This action just sets the password of a database to `nil`, effectively closing it. Once the database is closed, the UI should update: database icon should change to locked, and if you now select the database, it should go to the screen saying "Closed!".

That's the problem. If you try to close the `test` database from the example above, the icon correctly changes to locked; but you still go to the "Opened!" screen if you select the `test` databse after closing it. So the icon updates correctly, but the `NavigationLink`'s destination does not.

You can try out the example above to better understand the problem.

The interesting point is: if I extract the code from `NavigationLink`'s destination into a separate view, and pass the binding to it, the problem will be fixed.

First create a view containing everything we had in `NavigationLink`'s destination argument:

```swift
struct Destination: View {
    @Binding var database: Database
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if database.isOpen {
                Text("Opened!")
            } else {
                Text("Closed!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, use it in `NavigationLink`s destination, like this:

```swift
NavigationLink(
    destination: {
        Destination(database: $database)
    },
...
```

This fixes everything: if you close `test`, it goes to correct screen (the one saying "Closed!"). But why? Why does using a separate view work, but having the code in place doesn't? I'm new to SwiftUI and iOS development, and I don't understand this. Shouldn't the destination of `NavigationLink` update if `database.isOpen` has changed? Why doesn't SwiftUI pick up the changes made to `database.isOpen`?

Comment: Switch database to a struct

Comment: @loremipsum Wow, it actually worked! I still wonder why? Why SwiftUI doesn't like classes? If you have time, could you consider writing an answer explaining the details?

Comment: OK, I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468903/11004423 Thank you @loremipsum !

Comment: Short answer SwiftUI wrappers redraw when the value changes changing the property of a reference type doesn’t change the value you need something else like conformance to ObservableObject. Watch “Demystify SwiftUI” you can look through my previous answers too people ask this question every other day it seems depending on the question and my time I write the same thing tailored towards the specific question.

Comment: I actually prefer classes for my model objects as reference types especially in iOS 17+  with Observable. Apple changed everything.

Comment: @loremipsum Wow it's true! They simplified everything indeed, I just read this article: https://betterprogramming.pub/ios-17-observable-and-the-observation-framework-152deaf8fc5e Thank you for telling me this :)